# Agreggate rows from SQL combining values and removing NULLs into a single row

Tags: sql, db2, aggregation

I have the following query in DB2 for which I need to combine the rows with values with the ones with nulls into a single line, eventually removing the nulls when there is valid data for that column.

The SQL is

```
select z.po_id, scdc.ship_id, dcdc.ship_id, scus.ship_id, dcus.ship_id

from covinfos.ibm_plant_order z

left join COVINFOS.IPO_LINE_TO_CASE A ON z.po_id = a.po_id

left JOIN COVINFOS.SHIPMENT scus ON (A.SHIP_ID = scus.SHIP_ID AND A.SHIP_TO_LOC_CODE = scus.SHIP_TO_LOC_CODE and scus.loc_type = 'CUS')

left join COVINFOS.SHIPMENT_EVENT dcus ON (scus.SHIP_ID = dcus.SHIP_ID_856 AND scus.SHIP_TO_LOC_CODE = dcus.SHIP_TO_LOC_CD856 
AND dcus.SHIP_EVNT_CD = 'D')

left JOIN COVINFOS.SHIPMENT scdc ON (A.SHIP_ID = scdc.SHIP_ID AND A.SHIP_TO_LOC_CODE = scdc.SHIP_TO_LOC_CODE and scdc.loc_type = 'CDC')

left join COVINFOS.SHIPMENT_EVENT dcdc ON (scdc.SHIP_ID = dcdc.SHIP_ID_856 AND scdc.SHIP_TO_LOC_CODE = dcdc.SHIP_TO_LOC_CD856 
AND dcdc.SHIP_EVNT_CD = 'D')

where

z.po_id = 'BQG546'
```

The result is as seen in image below.

[image]

I would like to see just 1 row, grouping by PO_ID and only show the non null values when applicable (if the column has all nulls like column 3 then it would end up in null I assume)

I am using QMF for Workstation z/OS V11.1 Fix Pack 3 to run this query. I tried XMLCAST but not sure if I was using it correctly. LISTAGG seems to be not supported in this client. I would like to then implement it in Cognos BI so again it could work or not.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use aggregation:

```
select z.po_id, max(scdc.ship_id), max(dcdc.ship_id), max(scus.ship_id), max(dcus.ship_id)
from . . .
group by z.po_id;
```

There appears to be at most one non-NULL value in each column so `max()` suffices.

Comment: I had to add max() to all columns and just leave first in the group by (The image is a sample with less fields just to point out the issue) It is working now. Thanks